# How to set the post permalink using the WordPress REST API?

Tags: posts, permalinks, rest-api

When fetching the posts, I can access the `link` property which represents the full post link.

But when creating a post, what is the way to set that permalink value?

Setting the slug does not seem to work since I would like to set a permalink like `/foo/bar/post-slug`.

In the post edit UI, I can set it like this:

> [image]

Comment: You can’t set the link to something arbitrary. It’s generated based on the site’s permalink structure, the post’s slug, and whether it has any parents.

Comment: But in the WordPress post ui, I can do that.

Comment: You can change the slug, not the full URL. As such you can achieve the same thing by changing the _slug_ via the API.

Comment: @JacobPeattie no, that’s the full url

Comment: That's not a standard meta box in WordPress. You're using something custom to allow this. In which case the answer will be specific to whatever you're using. So you'll nee to ask its author.